# How can I create a nested list given a string where a new nested list is formed when specific punctuation is seen in the string?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

If I am given a string for example, "I like ham. I like cheese too! Do you?", and I want to create a nested list where a new list is created in the main list when a ".", "?", or"!" is seen. I have tried:

```
string = "I like ham. I like cheese too! Do you?"    
for i in string:  
    if i == "?" or i == "." or i == "!":  
        list = string.split(i)  
print(list)
```

This however, only works once and does not work if there is more than one period, question mark, or exclamation mark in the string. What I am trying to get as output is:

```
[['I', 'like', 'ham'], ['I', 'like', 'cheese', 'too'], ['Do', 'you']]
```

If anyone could help me that was be great! Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you are looking for:

```
>>> s = "I like ham. I like cheese too! Do you?"
>>> import re
>>> [sentence.split() for sentence in re.split('[?.!]', s) if sentence]
[['I', 'like', 'ham'], ['I', 'like', 'cheese', 'too'], ['Do', 'you']]
```

#### How it works

`re.split` will split a string on a regular expression:

```
>>> re.split('[?.!]', s)
['I like ham', ' I like cheese too', ' Do you', '']
```

where `[?.!]` is a regular expression that matches any of `?`, `.`, or `!`.

Once that we have split the string into sentences, we need to do one more step and that is split the sentences into words. So, as an example taking a single sentence:

```
>>> sentence = 'I like ham'
>>> sentence.split()
['I', 'like', 'ham']
```

We do the same to all sentences with:

```
>>> [sentence.split() for sentence in re.split('[?.!]', s) if sentence]
[['I', 'like', 'ham'], ['I', 'like', 'cheese', 'too'], ['Do', 'you']]
```

#### Notes

`list` is a python builtin and `string` is the name of a python standard library.  Since you might need them in the future, it is poor practice to overwrite them.  So, it is good form to pick other names for script variables.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without importing modules?